# getting error while doing minification of css files with gulp

Tags: gulp

Please advise i want to minify the .css files of my project with gulp so i have written the below task in my gulp.js file as shown below but still upon execution i am getting the error , please advise how to fix the below error

below is the code that I have written is

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifyCss = require("gulp-minify-css");
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    gulp.src('C:\\Softwares\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\target\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\static\\css\\*.css') // path to your file
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\Softwares\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\target\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\static\\cssoutput'));
});
```

below is the error i am getting upon execution

```
C:\Softwares\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample>gulp minify-css
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-minify-css'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Softwares\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\gulpfile.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. It cannot find the gulp-minify-css module . Do you use npm?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it cannot locate the module.  Have you run `npm install gulp-minify-css --save-dev`?

You may want to try re-installing your local packages / dependencies:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```